# Displaying html in email

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I have the following html/css document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
body {
   background-color:white;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

#outterBox {
   position:relative;
   width:500px;
   height:320px;
   display:flex;
   justify-content: top;
   flex-direction:column;
   background-color:#F0f0f0;
}

#innerBox {
   display:flex;
   align-self: center;
   background-color:white;
   width:90%;
   height:55%;
   margin-top:6px;
   flex-direction:column;
}

#headingBox {
   display:flex;
   align-self: flex-start;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#f0f0f0;
   overflow: hidden;
   height:18%;
   margin-top:6px;
}

#headingBox > img {
   margin-left:-4%;
   background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

#notiBar {
   display:flex;
   align-self: flex-start;
   background-color:#a1a1a1;
   width:100%;
   height:42px;
   justify-content: top;
   align-items: center;
}

#qqq > span {
   font-size:18px;
   color:white;
   margin:16px;
}

#nnn {
   display:flex;
   align-self: flex-start;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   justify-content: top;
   align-items: left;
   flex-direction:column;
}

#nnn > span {
   font-size:18px;
   color:#878787;
   margin-top:16px;
   margin-bottom:16px;
   margin-left:14px;
}

#nnn > a {
   display:flex;
   background-color:#5683CC;
   border:none;
   height:36px;
   color:white;
   font-size:14px;
   padding-left:10px;
   padding-right:10px;
   align-self:center;
   align-items:center;
   text-decoration:none;
}

#footer {
   display:flex;
   height:27%;
   width:90%;
   align-self: center;
}

#footer > span {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    color:#878787;
    font-size:10px;
 }

 #u {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#81a0d3;
    font-size:10px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="outterBox">
      <div id="headingBox">
         <img src="">
      </div>
      <div id="innerBox">
         <div id="qqq">
            <span>New</span>
         </div>
         <div id="nnn">
            <span><span id="aaa">John</span>, xxxxx</span>
            <a href="https://www.google.com"><span>Hello</span></a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
         <span> Some footer<a id="u" href="/"> click</a></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I send the email from my server with the following command:

```
mail -s "$(echo -e "This is Subject\nContent-Type: text/html")"  testemail@gmail.com < test.html
```

The rendering within the email is not how I see it when I open it within a browser. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here was I have no javascript. Is there a special way to get html to work within an email?

**When rendered from browser:**

[image]

**When sent to email:**
[image]

Also the image doesn't show either (left off within the html)

Comment: In which application do you open your email?

Comment: I use Chrome to open gmail

Comment: "The rendering within the email is not how I see it when I open it within a browser" — In what way is it different?

Comment: See edited question

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this methode. Hope it solves your problem:

```
  echo "<b>HTML Message goes here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" testemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: guessing this is the same as: cat test.html | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" testemail@gmail.com which gives the same result

Comment: for the image u can use online converter to base64 if that is convenient for you. Here is the link [link](https://www.base64-image.de/)

Comment: thanks John that's a good idea! however I don't know why the css formating isn't working correctly... Are there issues with including styles? Or could it be the flex box?

Comment: For some email clients they ignore the code in the head section.  For html emails your best bet is to do all styles inline, and if you can do it by html, then do.  Also, don't use divs so much, use tables for your layout 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Things I learnt during this exercise:

1. Don't try use flex boxes for email mark up (as at July 2017)
2. Don't try and use SVG images (either linking to a site or embedding)